# MySQL displays error #1064

Tags: mysql

This is the error that `MySQL` shows:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') REFERENCES `employee_management_portel_schema`.`Client_ref_table` () ' at line 16

My code is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee_management_portel_schema`.`Project_ref_table` (
  `project_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `project_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `project_description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `enabled_flag` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `project_start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `project_end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `client_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `created_on` DATE NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` DATE NOT NULL,
  `dept_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `project_id_UNIQUE` (`project_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `client_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `employee_management_portel_schema`.`Client_ref_table` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your SQL syntax.  Errors are pretty hard to read these days!

Comment: Have you tried removing the code at link 16 and seeing if it works then? Basically I don't think that syntax would work. Create the table in MySQL workbench and copy the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the column Name inside of `()` in this lines.

```
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `employee_management_portel_schema`.`Client_ref_table` ()
```

for more Information about using foreign keys look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).